# What would be some ideal parts for designing a custom audio crossover?

Tags: audio

I am trying to design a custom, audio line-level, crossover, to separate the AF into quadrants, according to the AF frequency, and then amplify these bands, to use as control circuits such as triacs or SCRs. Also, would it be possible to use toroidal cores for the inductors in the crossover section with LCR filters, or another type of filter together

Comment: google `color organ`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inductors are generally used in passive crossovers, those with no power source. If you’re going to be using amplification you may as well go with an active (powered) crossover which can be made using just op-amps, resistors and capacitors. You should be able to find circuits for these online.

Comment: Ok thanks, I just thought separating the frequency into bands before an op amp would've been the right way to go, but I will do some more research on that path